# ADAL Android:Unable to parse 'id_token' from acquiretoken response if the scope is defined as 'openid offline_access'

Tags: android, adal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

Following below mentioned steps to get the token from azure ad using adal android

- Version: 2.0.1-alpha
- calling the following method authcontext.acquireToken(context,scope,scope,additional_scope, EMAIL_SIGNIN_POLICY, client_id,redirect_uri,getUserInfo(),PromptBehavior.Auto,
  "nux=1&", getCallback())

  - scope is defined as "openid offline_access"
  - While debugging the application along with library, successful web response is received from adal as

  {"not_before":"****",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "id_token":"****",
    "id_token_expires_in":"****",
    "profile_info":"****",
    "refresh_token":"****",
    "refresh_token_expires_in":"*****"
   }

but when adal parses this response it fails as it refers below conditon in adal library

```
Oauth2.java
if(mRequest.isIdTokenRequest()){
    expiresInLookUp = "idtoken_expires_in";
    token = response.get(AuthenticationConstants.OAuth2.ID_TOKEN);
}

AuthenticationRequest.java
        boolean isIdTokenRequest() {
          if (mScope != null && mScope.length != 0) {
            for (String scope : mScope) {
                if (scope.equalsIgnoreCase("openid") || scope.equalsIgnoreCase(mClientId)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

- Changing the scope as "openid" results in exception as it refers the below condition in the library

  AuthenticationContext.java

  if (set.contains("openid")) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
              "API does not accept openid as a user-provided scope");
  }

Answer (score 0):

Pass ONLY client id as a scope to execute openid flow.

## update

This issue was fixed in 2.0.2-alpha.

Comment: Yes,Able to get the token successfully. 
But while saving the token adal caches it twice and next time fetching the token from adal cache throws the exception **Cache has multiple entries**  AuthorizationContext.java           `if(request.isIdTokenRequest()){ cacheItem.setScope(new String[]{request.getClientId()}); key.setScope(new String[]{request.getClientId()}); mTokenCacheStore.setItem(key, cacheItem); }`

Answer (score 0):

We already pass openid in the scope for you in our SDKs, which is why we have a catch to ensure you don't pass it again :-)

Comment: So what should be the value of scope ? 'openid' or 'openid offline_access' or 'value of client id'

Comment: The value of the client id. In our thinking, since you are getting a token only for yourself and not a resource the best way to demonstrate this is by using your client ID, which is "yourself". Let me know if you get it to work, and if so mark answered. Thanks!

Comment: Passing the scope as client id fetches the token successfully.

Comment: But while saving the token adal caches it twice and next time fetching the token from adal cache throws the exception'Cache has multiple entries                                                                AuthorizationContext.java                              `if(request.isIdTokenRequest()){
                cacheItem.setScope(new String[]{request.getClientId()});
                key.setScope(new String[]{request.getClientId()});
                mTokenCacheStore.setItem(key, cacheItem);
            }`

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the sample. However you've successfully received the token, so this has been answered. 

Keep in mind this is alpha ADAL release so the sample may have some issues as we build the product. Can you raise an issue in the sample repo? Otherwise the sample app in Android ADAL source itself may work better as that gets updated as we develop the experimental branch.  I'll also research this and come back to you soon with a solution in this space.

Comment: Sure will raise an issue.Please share the link of branch for library 2.0-alpha so that i can create an issue there